# Show that $A + B$ is a subspace of $H$ that contains $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Please hand tips and hints in solving:

Let $H$ be a vector space.
For $U_1, U_2$ subsets of $H$, define $U_1 + U_2$ to be the set $\{u_1 + u_2\,|\,u_1\in U_1 \wedge u_2 \in U_2\}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $H$.

$a)$ Show that $A + B$ is a subspace of $H$ that contains $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subset $S \subset H$, where $H$ is a vector space, is a **subspace** of $H$ if and only if: (i) $0\in S$, (ii) $\alpha x + \beta y\in S$ for every $x,y\in S$ and $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb F$, where $\mathbb F$ is the field that underlies the vector space $H$.

1. **$A+B$ contains $A$ and $B$:** Certainly $A \subset A + B$ and $B \subset A+B$ by definition of $A+B$, since $0\in A$ and $0\in B$ (they are subspaces).
2. **$A+B$ is a subspace:** To show that $A+B$ is a subspace of $H$, note first that $0\in A+B$ since $0\in A$ and $0\in B$. Also, if $a_1 + b_1\in A+B$ and $a_2 + b_2\in A+B$ where $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$, we have $\alpha (a_1 + b_1) + \beta(a_2+b_2)\in A+B$ for every $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb F$ (the field over which $H$ is a vector space). To see this, observe that $\alpha (a_1 + b_1) + \beta(a_2+b_2) = (\alpha a_1 + \beta a_2) + (\alpha b_1 + \beta b_2)$. Since $A$ is a subspace, $\alpha a_1 + \beta a_2 \in A$. Since $B$ is a subspace, $\alpha b_1 + \beta b_2 \in B$.

I have left some details for you to fill, and I hope you're able to take it from here. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: I just want to clarify, are these conditions that must be satisfied for $A+B$ to be a subspace of $H$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have added some clarification at the top of the answer. @muw

Comment: Thank you so much. I was aware of the three conditions for it to be a subspace of $H$. I was just not sure how to set it up (because of the form $A+B$). I notice that there are only two conditions in your answer? Did you leave the third one for me to solve in purpose?

Comment: @muw My second condition is equivalent to saying that (i) $\alpha x \in S$ for every $x\in S$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb F$, and (ii) $x + y \in S$ for every $x,y\in S$. I have combined these two conditions in one, in the form of $\alpha x + \beta y$ (you should see why they are equivalent), hence one lesser condition than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be a vector space over some field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $H$. We want to prove that $A+B$ as you defined is a subspace of $H$. Two things need to be notice. For $A+B$ be a subspace of $H$,

$(i)$ the set $A+B$ must be a subset of $H$; (and it is in fact, try to understand why)

$(ii)$ $A+B$ needs to be closed for the operations defined for $H$ and restricted to $A+B$.

The second point comes straight for the definition, but we also have a characterisation which is very handful to prove this sort of things. I will leave it here (I guess that you might already know it, but if you not, you should attempt to prove).

$\to$ Let $V$ be a vector space and $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq V$ with the operations defined in $V$ but restricted to $U$. Then, $U$ (together with these operations) is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $\alpha u + \beta v$, for all $u,v \in U$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{K}$.

These hints should be sufficient for your work.